# Storing objects in a static array from a dynamic array-Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a dynamic object array like this:

```
 private Array<Block> blocks=new Array<Block>();
```

I am iterating this array like this:

```
   for (Block b : blocks) {
    sytem.out.printlan(b);
 //eack block object should be taken and transfer to static array here
  }
```

I have an empty static array of same type here:

```
private Block frames[] = new Block[]{};//size should be  4
```

I want to take random elements from the blocks array and to store inside frame array?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `Random` library of java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).

You can do something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();

int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(blocks.size());

frames[i] = blocks.get(randomIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could use the `Random` built in class to generate random indexes.

And by using `Stream`, you could generate as many indexes as required, retrieve values from `blocks` and create the target array in a simple way.

Example to create the array with 4 random elements :

```
Block[] frames = new Random().ints(4, 0, blocks.size())
                             .mapToObj(i-> blocks.get(i))
                             .toArray(Block[]::new);
```

Note that you should store the generated index values if you want not reuse the same index twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private Block frames[] = new Block[4];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Its a 3 character change, its self explained. Add a explanation will decrease the readability. Its intuitive, a explanation is not required for intuitive coding, thats why we call it intuitive.